# How to easily format Python for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to format Python scripts so they can be added to a Stack Overflow question. What is an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Sure, wasn't sure about the etiquette of answering my own question.

Answer (score -2):

Per 'The Photon' who is both bright and massless, I'm answering my own question.
Feel free to enhance the script. I'll upvote and if something really good shows up, choose that as the preferred answer.

```
f0 = '    '+open('Stack_Overflow_Answer.py','r').read().replace('   ','    ').replace('\n','\n    ')
f1 = open('stacked.txt','w')
f1.write(f0)
f1.close()
```

Use as is, or season to taste with `sys.argv` or `input()`.  Enjoy!

Comment: There ... a few points for the helpful effort.  I agree, though, that this might belong in *meta* for possible inclusion in help documentation.

Comment: I guess you should also rewrite the question to only have the question part. By the way, if you put that in a utility, you might want to make the prefix space configurable (putting code inside a list requires 8 spaces).

Comment: How is reading from a (fixed!) filename and writing to a text file the "easy way" that you asked for, when all one has to do is select the script then press `Ctrl+K` (or click the Code button in the toolbar)?